# If a dependency is only used in a single method, should I inject it or use service location?

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, lazy-loading

I am bit new to dependency injection & came across subjected question while working.

Lets say I have a class 'Employee' which has one method this method say 'Promote' gets conditionally called that too on rarest scenario.

'Promote' method uses an object of 'ValueAddition', now is it best practice to have this objected injected via constructor & user global object or should I 
resolve the dependency in method itself?

What is recommended best practice? or any pointer on the life time of resolved dependency would be helpful.

Comment: This is a good question that is more generally about how to use DI than about Autofac specifically. I'm going to update your question title to get a more targeted set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you should always look to inject dependencies rather than use service location (ie, resolving a dependency directly from the inversion of control container). [There's a great, pretty well known blog article here called "Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern" that can help clarify the reasons.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

You may run into other issues as you expand that seem to point you to using service location. In general, you really should design around those issues instead of falling back to service location.

- **I only need the object in one method.** Consider moving the functionality of the method to a different object. For example, maybe the `Promote()` method should be on an `IEmployeePromoter` where you resolve that and it takes the special object. Then you'd call `Promote(Employee)` and pass in the employee rather than changing the dependencies for an `Employee`. Sometimes your inversion of control container will have a way to generate a factory (like `Func<T>` or `Lazy<T>`) to help you defer resolution until you actually need it.
- **I have way too many dependencies.** Usually this means your object is doing too much. The [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) can help you refactor your objects to be a more manageable size. Smaller objects generally need fewer dependencies because they have far fewer concerns to manage.

There's a good amount of documentation and books out there on the pattern of dependency injection. It might be good to widen the scope of your search to looking at the patterns and practices in general when not applied to a particular framework (or even language) and it can help inform you of best practices in your own code.

Comment: Thanks Travis, this helps!